# creating barchart with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a bar chart with `matplotlib` using `python 3.7`. 
This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
import numpy as np
pos=np.arange(6)+0.5

matplotlib.pyplot.bar(pos(4,8,12,3,17,6),align="center",color="red")
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-29-97c1c7ce69fe>", line 3, in <module>
 matplotlib.pyplot.bar(pos(4,8,12,3,17,6),align="center",color="red")
 TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Comment: Just replace `pos(4,8,12,3,17,6)` by `pos`. But these are just the x-values. Where are the frequencies/y values which you want to plot. Oh yeah, the mystery of the missing comma

Comment: matplotlib.pyplot.bar(pos,(4,8,12,3,17,6),align="center",color="red")

Comment: @Bazingaa I guess `(4,8,12,3,17,6)` is the second argument

Comment: Yeah, it got me. @Eliza: By the way, please do import as `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and write `plt.bar` and `plt.show()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot a comma between `pos` and `(4,8,12,3,17,6)`:

```
 matplotlib.pyplot.bar(pos,(4,8,12,3,17,6),align="center",color="red")
```

Output:
[image]